# Show Card View inside Recycler View with previous and next object

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, paging, android-cardview

I am trying to create a horizontal recyclerview with cardview like below where the main Card is in the center and the previous and the next card have a partial visibility.  [image: and]

Is it possible to achive this without having 3 cardviews in the one layout ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Inside a `RecyclerView` item row, you only need one `CardView` because each time an item is created it'll inflate that layout for how many items have been passed into the `RecyclerViewAdapter` but instead of having that `CardView`'s width being `match_parent` or `fill_parent`, you can assign it a width statically (for all screens) by assigning it a value.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    ....

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In this case the `CardView` has a width of `200dp`.

**Note:** Doing it this way will require you to change the dimensions based on the  device that is being used.

Comment: instead of `200dp` (or whatever fixed value) you can set the width (for example to 80% of the parent's width) in `LayoutParams` inside `onCreateViewHolder`